# WORDPRESS: Disable comments in "News" Category and Enable in "Blog" Category?

Tags: wordpress, templates, comments, categories

I have a News page that displays all the posts within the "News" Category. This category has sub-categories such as "Merchandise, Music, Events" ect.

I am aiming to remove comments from ALL News/Sub-category posts but only display them with the "Blog" Category posts.

Right now I have my `single.php` set up so posts with the "Gallery" `post_format` structure are displayed differently.

**Here is the single.php file//**
http://pastebin.com/YNf3TxT6

I am wondering what I have to fix in order to get this working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: For future viewers, here is the updated paste from the conversation below for a single.php that will only show the comments template if the post is in the "Blog" Category: [pastebin.com/y9ZtCN5U](http://pastebin.com/y9ZtCN5U)**

Assuming you put your Blog posts on a page separate from your news posts, you should be able to use different templates based on category.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

So, you could make a category-blog.php template file that doesn't include the comments code.

If all of your categories are being listed on the same page, use this instead of the in_category stuff on line 50.

```
<?php
foreach (get_the_category() as $category) {
    if ( $category->name == 'Blog' ) {
        comments_template();
    }
}
?>
```

Not 100% sure that will work, but try it out and let me know what happens.

Comment: I'd actually like comments to be shown in blog categories and excluded with the news Categories...does the code apply to that? Also, where exactly do I place this code? Do I replace the old `<?php if (in_category('news')) : ?>
<?php else : ?>
<?php comments_template(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
  ` with the new code?

Comment: The code above will show the comments template if the post has the Blog category. If it doesn't, no comments will display.

Comment: I updated my single.php file but no luck :( The comment form is still displayed on the news category posts. To be sure, does this code work with the News Sub-categories? Because "News" is actually a parent Category.

Comment: Hmm.  I reverted back to the in_category function on one of my own wordpress installs and it works.  New paste: http://pastebin.com/y9ZtCN5U